# Why does angular2 need nodejs 5

Tags: angular

I just came from the angular.io (https://angular.io/guide/quickstart) site.

In their quick start under prerequisites they suggest to use nodejs 5.  My question is ( I have been looking all over the web and gitter)  Why do angular2 need nodejs 5 in specific?

What tools, feature or script depend on nodejs 5.  I was able to create an angular2 web app using nodejs 4.4.2 and I had no problem.

I totally understand that some of the uses of nodejs in angular2 is mainly to for transpiling typescript and running the webserver to serve your app.

If anyone can help me with this question I will greatly appreciate it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What really matters imho is the version of the package manager `npm` which should be `> 3.0` at least on windows machines because of the flattened `node_module` structure.

Since most of your dependencies will be `node_modules` and you will have many of those, you will have problems deploying angular 2 applications on an IIS Server (at least for development purposes where you don't bundle / minify it all together), because of the maximum file path length of 255 characters.

`npm` with version above `3` ships with nodejs from version `5.x` on.

That's the only reason i could think of. As Günther Zöchbauer stated in his answer, you don't necessarily need a node.js server to run your angular 2 app.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need at all. You can use any web server to server your Angular2 application. Server-side rendering also supports other servers than Nodejs.

Comment: I figure that. Correct i can use any server like u said. I Just did not know if nodejs 5 was strictly necessary for development, tools, scripts, processes, features, etc.